# What does CTCol object do and what does it stand for with POI?

Tags: java, charts, apache-poi

I am new to POI.

I wanted to set a font to all cells in a sheet.

So, I found out I can achieve it with code below:

```
CTCol cTCol = ((XSSFSheet) sheet).getCTWorksheet().getColsArray(0).addNewCol();
cTCol.setMin(1);
cTCol.setMax(16384);
cTCol.setWidth(12.7109375);
cTCol.setStyle(cellStyle.getIndex());
```

But I cannot find out how CTCol object works.

Therefore, I would like to ask:

1. How it works.
2. Additionally I would like to know what CT stands for in CTCol.

Is there anyone who would be nice to explain it?

Thank you in advance!

Hope you have a lovely day :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `XSSFWorkbook` of `apache poi` is an `Excel` workbook in [Office Open XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) format.

> Office Open XML (also informally known as OOXML or Microsoft Open XML
>   (MOX)[3]) is a zipped, XML-based file format developed by Microsoft[4]
>   for representing spreadsheets, charts, presentations and word
>   processing documents. The format was initially standardized by Ecma
>   (as ECMA-376), and by the ISO and IEC (as ISO/IEC 29500) in later
>   versions.

For programming this, `apache poi`'s [high level classes](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/index.html) bases on low level classes from  [ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.apache.poi|ooxml-schemas|1.3|jar). Some of them are also shipped with `poi-ooxml-schemas-version-yyyymmdd.jar`.

Unfortunately there is not any documentation about those `ooxml-schemas` classes for `Java` anymore. Formerly at least third party documentations were available. But currently they all are unavailable. So only possibility for getting documentation for this is getting [ooxml-schemas-1.3-sources.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/ooxml-schemas/1.3/ooxml-schemas-1.3-sources.jar) and then doing `javadoc` using those sources.

Background: The `ooxml-schemas` are the `XSD` schema definitions for `Office Open XML` converted to `Java` classes. The schema defines `xsd:complexType`s. So the `CT` in the `ooxml-schemas` class names stands for **C**omplex**T**ype.

For the `XML` schema definitions see [Ecma Office Open XML File Formats Standard - Final draft - 9th of October 2006](http://www.ecma-international.org/news/TC45_current_work/TC45-2006-50_final_draft.htm).

The complex type named `CT_Col` defines column settings for `SpreadsheetML` which is described in chapter **3.3.1.12 col (Column Width & Formatting)** of [Office Open XML Ecma TC45 Final Draft Part 4: Markup Language Reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/news/TC45_current_work/Office%20Open%20XML%20Part%204%20-%20Markup%20Language%20Reference%20(tagged).pdf).

The following XML Schema fragment defines the contents of this element:

```
<complexType name="CT_Col">
 <attribute name="min" type="xsd:unsignedInt" use="required"/>
 <attribute name="max" type="xsd:unsignedInt" use="required"/>
 <attribute name="width" type="xsd:double" use="optional"/>
 <attribute name="style" type="xsd:unsignedInt" use="optional" default="0"/>
 <attribute name="hidden" type="xsd:boolean" use="optional" default="false"/>
 <attribute name="bestFit" type="xsd:boolean" use="optional" default="false"/>
 <attribute name="customWidth" type="xsd:boolean" use="optional" default="false"/>
 <attribute name="phonetic" type="xsd:boolean" use="optional" default="false"/>
 <attribute name="outlineLevel" type="xsd:unsignedByte" use="optional" default="0"/>
 <attribute name="collapsed" type="xsd:boolean" use="optional" default="false"/>
</complexType>
```